# How To Add Histogram Frequency Data from Loaded CSV File in R

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, histogram

I load a file that has two columns of random numbers

```
RandomNumbers <- read.csv("~/Documents/RandomNumbers.csv")
```

Now, I can make a histogram of one of those columns of data by doing something like this:

```
x <- hist(Cell2, breaks=seq(0,20000, by=1000)
```

My ultimate goal, however, is to simply get the histogram frequency data, which I can get by doing this

```
x$breaks
x$counts
```

and add each value of each row of just the counts to the the counts column from my other table column.

I want to basically average or add together two separate histograms that are generated from two columns of numbers I loaded in my CSV file.

Ultimately, I will have more than 2 columns/histograms to add together, thus creating a smoother distribution.

How can I most easily do this in R? Please keep in mind I'm very new to R, so I'd prefer basic functions over fancier stuff if possible.

Comment: what does this mean: "and add each value of each row of just the counts to the the counts column from my other table column"? I can't make sense of what you are trying to get. - nevermind, I think I got it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, just put the file name, the columns in the file you want to create histogram data for, and the breaks for the histograms. The output file variable "breaks" includes only the lower limit of the bin.

```
>x = pmin(exp(rnorm(20)), 20)
>y = pmin(exp(rnorm(20)), 20)
>write.csv(data.frame(x,y),"/Users/foo/temp/randcsv.csv", row.names=FALSE)


>sumhists = function(file, cols=1:2, brk){
>   dat = read.csv(file, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
>   nbins = length(brk)-1
>   nvars = length(cols)
>   newdat = matrix(NA, nrow=nbins, ncol=nvars+1)
>    newdat[,1] = brk[1:nbins]
>   for (col in cols) {
>    h=hist(dat[,col], plot=FALSE, breaks=brk)
>     newdat[,col+1] = h$counts
>    }
>    outdat = data.frame(newdat)
>    names(outdat) = c("breaks", names(dat)[cols])
>    outdat$total = rowSums(outdat[,-1])
>    return(outdat)
>   }

>#add countsd   
>sumhists("/Users/foo/temp/randcsv.csv", cols=1:2, brk=seq(0,20, by=1))

   breaks  x  y total
1       0 12 13    25
2       1  3  7    10
3       2  2  0     2
4       3  2  0     2
5       4  0  0     0
6       5  0  0     0
7       6  1  0     1
8       7  0  0     0
9       8  0  0     0
10      9  0  0     0
11     10  0  0     0
12     11  0  0     0
13     12  0  0     0
14     13  0  0     0
15     14  0  0     0
16     15  0  0     0
17     16  0  0     0
18     17  0  0     0
19     18  0  0     0
20     19  0  0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several simple ways to do this. You can add things manually if its just two or 3 columns.

```
dataA=rnorm(50)
dataB=rnorm(50)
A=hist(dataA,breaks=(seq(-6,6,by=1)))$counts
B=hist(dataB,breaks=(seq(-6,6,by=1)))$counts
avedata=mean(A+B)
avedata
```

Or if there are several columns you can use a `for` and `apply` type function. Using something like this **(not tested)**.

```
avedata=NULL
datamatrix=matrix(NA,length("breaks"),"number of cols")
for(i in 1:"number of cols"){datamatrix[,i]=hist(yourdata[,i],breaks= (seq(-6,6,by=1))$counts)}
for(i in 1:length("breaks")){avedata[i]=datamatrix[i,]}
avedata
```

Answer (score 0):

The [HistogramTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistogramTools/) package on CRAN has a number of functions for adding histograms together and otherwise manipulating histograms.  For summing together 2 or more histograms you would just use the `AddHistograms` function like this:

```
hist.1 <- hist(c(1,2,3,4), plot=FALSE)
hist.2 <- hist(c(1,2,2,4), plot=FALSE)
hist.sum <- AddHistograms(hist.1, hist.2)
hist.3 <- hist(c(1,2,2,4), plot=FALSE)
hist.sum <- AddHistograms(hist.1, hist.2, hist.3)
```